# Same API key for multiple projects

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with different projects related to google maps in android (just for practise). But for each project i have to generate an API key which is frustating. So is it possible to use same API key for multiple projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but this projects have to have the same packageId

Comment: The projects don't need to have the same package ID.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,you can use same API key for multiple projects by "choosing None option in Application restrictions category of Credential for API in Google developer console" and then you can use same API key for multiple project(well none option is by default selected while you create api key,you just have to 'enable that API key for maps sdk').
[API key restriction in Google Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1eIe.png)

Comment: But I guess this is not the recommended option